# Problems with my conditionals in single.php by category

Tags: categories, conditional-content, single

In my single.php file I would like to have a conditional that checks for the category of the post and display certain images and layout. Here is what I have: http://pastebin.com/dy6TE1yr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category

Example:

```php
<?php if ( in_category('rabbis-weekly-commentary') ) : ?>                   
<div id="inner_header">
<img src="http://www.ifcj.ca/ifcj_ca/images/elements/commentary_header.gif" border="0">
...
<?php elseif ( in_category('yaels-weekly-commentary') ) : ?>                    
<div id="inner_header">
<img src="http://www.ifcj.ca/ifcj_ca/images/elements/commentary_header.gif" border="0">
```